# Passing image to modal django with jquery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I'm trying to pass data on the modal with the help of jquery. I was successful passing all text related data but I'm unsure how would it work for images. As we use the {% static %} tag to show the images. It wouldn't just show on the passed modal.

Loop from where the data is being taken.

```
<div class="animals" id="cats" >
        {% for animals in cats  %}
                <div class="animalInfo" id="animalInfoID" data-image = "{{ animals.image.url }}" data-name="{{ animals.name }}" data-ageyears="{{ animals.age }}"
                        data-agemonths="{{ animals.age_months }}" data-gender="{{ animals.gender }}" data-description="{{ animals.description }}"  onclick="showContainer()">
                    <img class="animalPic" src="{{ animals.image.url }}" alt="">
                    <div class="animalDesc">
                        <h1>{{ animals.name }}</h1>
                        <p>{{ animals.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Modal where data is passed

```
    <div class="mainAdoptionPopContainer" id="mainAdoptionContainerId" style="display: none;">
        <img src="{% static 'adoptions/imgs/close-container.png' %}" onclick="hideContainer()" class="closeContainer" id="closeContainerID" alt="Close Pop Up">
        <div class="adoptionPopImageContainer">
            <img id="adoptionPopImage" src=""></img>
        </div>
        <div class="adoptionPopAnimalInfo">
            <div class="adoptionPopAnimalInfoTitle">
                <span id="adoptionPopName"><b></b></span> |
                <span id="adoptionPopGender"><b></b></span> |
                <span><span id="adoptionPopAge"></span> Year <span class="adoptionPopAgeMonths"></span>Months</span> |
                <span id="adoptionPopBreed"><b></b></span>    
            </div>
            <span class="adoptionDescription" id="adoptionDescriptionID"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

    $('.animalInfo').click(function(){
        $("#adoptionPopName").html($(this).data("name"));
        $("#adoptionPopImage").html($(this).data("image.url"));
        $("#adoptionPopGender").html($(this).data('gender'));
        $("#adoptionPopBreed").html($(this).data('breed'));
        $("#adoptionPopAge").html($(this).data('ageyears'));
        $("#adoptionPopAgeMonths").html($(this).data('agemonths'));
        $("#adoptionPopBreed").html($(this).data('breed'));
        $("#adoptionDescriptionID").html($(this).data('description'));
    });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `src` of the `<img>`, they have no innerHTML

```
 $("#adoptionPopImage").attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
```

Also the data attribute is `data-image` and has no *"url"* in it's name